# How to query if a website has SSL certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, httprequest

Is it possible querying websites to check if they have SSL certificate or not? I know we can do

```
Request.IsSecureConnection
```

but couldn't find how to query an external domain. I tried

```
 HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("something.com");
return webrequest.IsSecureConnection
```

and it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try connecting to `https://something.com`.

Comment: if they're doing ssl, they have to have a cert. whether that cert is valid or not is another question.

Comment: But I already asked how to check SSL certificate? If you find it confusing please edit title

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried that too but IsSecureConnection method does not show up when I use a webrequest, no matter what the address is. It only works with HttpContext.Current.Request

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to check is to see whether they accept connections on the secure port, 443. This doesn't prove they have a valid SSL certificate, but it's a start.

Here's a code sample:

```
try 
{
    var client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("something.com", 443);
    Console.WriteLine("SSL found");
} 
catch (SocketException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SSL not found");
}
```